# Командная строка не отображает русские буквы

Tags: windows, ruby, windows-7

Всем привет! Проблема в следующем... 
Например, когда я ввожу в командную строку
`project = Project.create title: "My project"`, английская раскладка все вводит без проблем и все работает. 
Но стоит мне переключиться на русскую раскладку, то `project = Project.create title:` ничего не отображает

Вот в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: ОС какая? Проблема только в рубишной консоли, или в терминале вообще?

Comment: Ос Windows 7, в терминале вообще.